# Desc order of a Join Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models

```
categories (id, name, ....)
users (id, name, ....)
categories_users (category_id, user_id)
```

I want to pull the top 5 categories associated with the number of users. right now i am using `category.users.count` to fetch the number. Is there a smarter way to calculate this on the fly and get the top Categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use group:

```
cate_ids = CategoryUser.select("count(user_id) as user_count, category_id").group("category_id").order("user_count desc").limit(5).map(&:category_id)
categories = Category.find(cate_ids)
```